# React Router - apply same onEnter function across routes

Tags: authentication, reactjs, react-router

I'm using react router and thinking about implementing auth. I would like to intercept the majority of requests and check if a user is authorised, and if not, redirect them.

The way I'm planning to do this is use the `onEnter` hook in the `Route` component. Rather than have to add this `onEnter` function to almost every route, is there a simple way to apply this behaviour across all routes, and "opt out" of the few that this behaviour doesn't apply to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a personal route between group of private routes.

`<Route component={Authorization} accessRoles={['admin', 'registered']}>
  ... This routes which need to authorization ...
</Route>`

I also send accessRoles to component Authorization for check role.

Comment: Ok. And in your Authorization component, what hook/function do you implement to redirect if user is not authorised? You do it in the render() function?

Comment: I created functionality on the cdm/cwrp
`checkAuth (props) {
        const { accessRoles } = props.route;

        if (!checkAuth(accessRoles, props.auth)) {
            history.pushState(null, '/signin?next=' + props.location.pathname);
        }
    }`